# Browser compatible code which take values from hidden field and pass it through query string on to other page

Tags: vb.net

Right now I am using this code on client side.

```
function winChangeOption()
{
    window.open("../Reports/AdjustedPrincipal_Filter.aspx?schemeid=" + document.getElementById("hfSchemeID").value + "&PropertyRefID=" + document.getElementById("hfPropertyRefID").value + "&DatePart=" + document.getElementById("hfDatePart").value ,"AdjustedPrincipal_Filter","top=150,left=180,height=250,width=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no")
    window.close();
}
```

The values for the hidden fields are already set. I want these value to open a window, in which the fields will be already filled using the values passed by this page.

This code is working fine on Internet Explorer, but not on other browsers. Moreover, when I don't pass any value and just open the required window, it works on all browsers.

Is there a browser compatible solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's your problem or not, but it looks like you need a semicolon before window.close();

Also, I would recommend changing your code like so:

```
function winChangeOption()
{
  var hfSchemID = document.getElementById("hfSchemeID").value;
  var hfPropertyRefID = document.getElementById("hfPropertyRefID").value;
  var hfDatePart = document.getElementById("hfDatePart").value;

  window.open("../Reports/AdjustedPrincipal_Filter.aspx?schemeid=" + 
                  hfSchemeID + "&PropertyRefID=" + 
                  hfPropertyRefID + "&DatePart=" + hfDatePart
              ,"AdjustedPrincipal_Filter"
              ,"top=150,left=180,height=250,width=600," + 
                  "location=no,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no," + 
                  "scrollbars=no,resizable=no");
  window.close();
```

}

This will give you the change to see if one of your getElementById calls are failing, which is what I would suspect your problem is.

Comment: thank you.But there was no problem regarding the semicolon.But this code is working fine.Thank you for response.

Comment: What about a failure of getElementById?

Comment: getElementById is working fine.Actually the code is working fine now.The problem was "function window.onload(){.......}" in the starting after the <script> tag.  Actually this doesn't work on all browsers.Even all functions like "function document.documentElement.onclick(){....}", onkeypress,onkeyup etc.Please tell me about some solution for the same.What to use in place of these types of functions.Moreover ,common functions declared in the js class also doesn't work.So,there are many problems with me right now regarding browser compatibility.Please help me .

Comment: @vebby: If you're running into a lot of cross browser issues, I would suggest looking into using an existing framework (jQuery is quite popular). For the onload event, jQuery has .ready() which is executed once the DOM has loaded, and .keypress() for onkeypress and so forth. jQuery and other cross browser frameworks were developed for a reason...there are LOTS of differences in the implementations.

Comment: Actually i am new in this field,just started working.So don't know much about jQuery,i have heard about it.But i will explore it for sure.Thanks for the response.

Comment: need an another option to use in place of window .onload(){....},  
window.document.onclick() and other functions like onkeyup(),onkeypress() on the aspx page.  
This i want on aspx page because i want to call javascript functions on onload,click or key press.So,if write them on server side on Pageload event then have to write that function on vb page and aspx page both.So i want something for aspx page only.  
Please help.